# How to use php preg_split to split a string and keep part of the used delimiter?

Tags: php, regex

I need to use preg_split to split the string below by using "};{" as the delimiter. But I want to keep/return the `}` and `{` in the returned array.

Regex can do so much, but wondering if this is possible using preg_split.

```
{'aid':10,'aSL'{'ac':true,'g_ac':true,'stats':0,'ldb':0,'g_':0},'hs':'4.8','l_p':1229241600},{'aid':80,'aSL':{'ac':0,'g_ac':0,'stats':0,'ldb':0,'g_':0}},{'aid':100,'aSL':{'ac':0,'g_ac':0,'stats':0,'ldb':0,'g_':0}},{'aid':30,'aSL':{'ac':true,'g_ac':true,'stats':0,'ldb':0,'g_':0}},{'aid':40,'aSL':{'ac':0,'g_ac':0,'stats':0,'ldb':0,'g_':0}},{'aid':60,'aSL':{'ac':true,'g_ac':true,'stats':0,'ldb':0,'g_':0}}
```

I want it to return like this

```
[0] => {'aid':10,'aSL':{'ac':true,'g_ac':true,'stats':0,'ldb':0,'g_':0},'hs':'4.8','l_p':1229241600}
[1] => {'aid':80,'aSL':{'ac':0,'g_ac':0,'stats':0,'ldb':0,'g_':0}
[2] => {'aid':100,'aSL':{'ac':0,'g_ac':0,'stats':0,'ldb':0,'g_':0}
[3] => {'aid':30,'aSL':{'ac':true,'g_ac':true,'stats':0,'ldb':0,'g_':0}
[4] => {'aid':40,'aSL':{'ac':0,'g_ac':0,'stats':0,'ldb':0,'g_':0}
[5] => {'aid':60,'aSL':{'ac':true,'g_ac':true,'stats':0,'ldb':0,'g_':0}
```

Comment: that's basically a json string. why not treat it like json and decode into a native structure. it'd be far easier to extract whatever bits you want and re-encode to json from that.

Comment: yeah that is how I eventually did it using json_decode, but still very curious how to keep part of the delimiter when using preg_split or similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To not include `}` `{` in the split-sequence, could use [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) instead:

`(?<=}),(?={)` or `(?<=});(?={)`

[Test at regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/pJ1lN5/1)

---

For use with the regex-functions need to put that into [delimiters](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php): `/pattern/`

Comment: Also, it's worth mentioning, that for case a two "," can happen one after one (we're not assume it's JSON as above, but any string, like: `},,,,{x},{y},,{`), we need to use `(?<=(?:}|,)),(?=(?:{|,))` or `(?<=(}|,)),(?=({|,))` - so we can include comma as before/after character too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Regex Look behind and look ahead:

```
<?php

$string = "{'aid':10,'aSL'{'ac':true,'g_ac':true,'stats':0,'ldb':0,'g_':0},'hs':'4.8','l_p':1229241600},{'aid':80,'aSL':{'ac':0,'g_ac':0,'stats':0,'ldb':0,'g_':0}},{'aid':100,'aSL':{'ac':0,'g_ac':0,'stats':0,'ldb':0,'g_':0}},{'aid':30,'aSL':{'ac':true,'g_ac':true,'stats':0,'ldb':0,'g_':0}},{'aid':40,'aSL':{'ac':0,'g_ac':0,'stats':0,'ldb':0,'g_':0}},{'aid':60,'aSL':{'ac':true,'g_ac':true,'stats':0,'ldb':0,'g_':0}}";

$matches = preg_split('/(?<=}),(?={)/', $string);

var_dump($matches);
```

Returns:

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  string(92) "{'aid':10,'aSL'{'ac':true,'g_ac':true,'stats':0,'ldb':0,'g_':0},'hs':'4.8','l_p':1229241600}"
  [1]=>
  string(59) "{'aid':80,'aSL':{'ac':0,'g_ac':0,'stats':0,'ldb':0,'g_':0}}"
  [2]=>
  string(60) "{'aid':100,'aSL':{'ac':0,'g_ac':0,'stats':0,'ldb':0,'g_':0}}"
  [3]=>
  string(65) "{'aid':30,'aSL':{'ac':true,'g_ac':true,'stats':0,'ldb':0,'g_':0}}"
  [4]=>
  string(59) "{'aid':40,'aSL':{'ac':0,'g_ac':0,'stats':0,'ldb':0,'g_':0}}"
  [5]=>
  string(65) "{'aid':60,'aSL':{'ac':true,'g_ac':true,'stats':0,'ldb':0,'g_':0}}"
}
```